# Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState on super.onBackPressed()

Tags: android, onbackpressed

I am displaying an interstitial ad when the user presses back to exit the application:

```
mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
   @Override
   public void onAdClosed() {
        onBackPressed(); //line 98
   }
});

requestNewInterstitial();

private void requestNewInterstitial() {
   AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
   mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
      mInterstitialAd.show();
   } else {
      super.onBackPressed(); //line 410
   }
}
```

This is the crash report I received from my users:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.myapp/com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3088)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3043)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3021)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:138)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1253)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1323)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:493)
at android.app.Activity.onBackPressed(Activity.java:2215)
at com.myapp.MainActivity.onBackPressed(MainActivity.java:410)
at com.myapp.MainActivity$1.onAdClosed(MainActivity.java:98)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzc.onAdClosed(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzm$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.l.a(SourceFile:109)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.a.n(SourceFile:645)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.b.t(SourceFile:351)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.t.t(SourceFile:141)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.overlay.ab.n(SourceFile:672)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.overlay.ab.i(SourceFile:408)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.overlay.a.d.onTransact(SourceFile:86)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdj$zza$zza.onPause(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity.onPause(Unknown Source)
at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:5335)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1233)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3074)
```

I understand that it is triggered when the user closes the ad, but why does it die on `super.onBackPressed()`?

Comment: Did you get solution of the problem? I am running to similiar issue.

Answer (score 15):

You can't call `onBackPressed()` when your activity is paused. However, the behavior on a back press is to leave the activity. Just call `finish()` instead of `onBackPressed()`.

You should make sure in your `onBackPressed()`'s override that the activity is going to finish. Back can be pressed for other reasons.

Comment: But why Android calls onBackPressed when the activity is paused? I mean, I didn't call this method by myself, so it must be called when the user hit the back button.

Answer (score 5):

You can see the stack trace showing that the error is caused by FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate.

This is just similar to `onActivityResult`, seems when you show the interstitial ad, you activity is put into pause, and when `onAdClosed()`, your app is not yet resumed.

To solve that, you can try to set a flag in `onAdClosed()`, and call `onBackPressed()` in `onResume()` if the flag is on.